how to find list of contributors in git repo for a particular folder from begining of the repo
I have a situation, where I want to segregate the folder structures depending on the frequency and contributors of a particular folder from a repo. And, create separate repos

Can you please [edit] your question to include your question in the question itself and also clarify how this is a web apps question?

To list the contributors for a particular folder in a Git repository, you can use the following command:
git log --pretty="%an" -- <path_to_folder> | sort | uniq

Explanation:

git log: This command lists the commit history.
--pretty="%an": This formats the output to show only the author's name (%an).
-- <path_to_folder>: This limits the log to changes made within a specific folder.
sort: This sorts the names alphabetically.
uniq: This removes duplicate names, giving you a unique list of contributors.

If you are on Windows, you can use Git Bash to run the above command.
If you want to iterate over every folder in the git repo and list the contributors for each folder, you can use the following command:
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "Contributors for folder: {}"; git log --pretty="%an" -- "{}" | sort | uniq; echo' \;

